# Listener or radio button value change JQuery v3.5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have looked to several other Q/A's on here that stretch several years back on older versions of JQuery.

I have setup my **HTML** like so:

```
<ul class="choose-date-range">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="30-days" name="date-range" value="30-days">
        <label for="30-days">30 days</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="60-days" name="date-range" value="60-days">
        <label for="60-days">60 days</label>
    </li>
    <li>
       <input type="radio" id="90-days" name="date-range" value="90-days">
       <label for="90-days">90 days</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and My **JavaScript** like so:

```
$('input:radio[name="date-range"]').on('click', function () {

    alert("test: " + $(this).val());

    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case '30-days':
            //ajax GET function
            break;

        case '60-days':
            //ajax GET function
            break;

        case '90-days':
            //ajax GET function
            break;
    }
});
```

I've tried a variety of older ways such as:

```
jQuery("#30-days").attr('checked', true);

jQuery("input[value='30-days']").attr('checked', true);

$('input:radio[name="date-range"]').on('check', function () {

$('input:radio[name="date-range"]').checked(function () {

$('input:radio[name="date-range"]').clicked(function () {
```

Thus far noth'n...

If anyone knows what the most recent syntax is (I have tried these in older versions and they work), that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: So your title says change and you did not try change? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `change` event.

```js
$('input:radio[name="date-range"]').on('change', function () {

    alert("test: " + $(this).val());

    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case '30-days':
            //ajax GET function
            break;

        case '60-days':
            //ajax GET function
            break;

        case '90-days':
            //ajax GET function
            break;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="choose-date-range">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="30-days" name="date-range" value="30-days">
        <label for="30-days">30 days</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="60-days" name="date-range" value="60-days">
        <label for="60-days">60 days</label>
    </li>
    <li>
       <input type="radio" id="90-days" name="date-range" value="90-days">
       <label for="90-days">90 days</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @NoahEldreth No problem.